# Why is typeof my variable an object, and not a number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which has a couple cells that contain simple numbers (IE: 1.00, 1000.00, 10000.00). I'm trying to format the cell contents using the 'format' function below. I have had success with this function in a different area of my code, but for whatever reason (the reason why I'm here) when I try to feed the contents of the table cells in, it doesn't work as I expected.

The problem is that the typeof my cell contents is 'object' and not 'number', so it skates right by the if statement and just returns my original value back to me. Is there a way I can coerce the data to be typeof number? I thought `var n = new Number(cellText);` would do the trick,  however, the typeof comes back as object. Confused.

In globalize.js:

```
Globalize.format = function( value, format, cultureSelector ) {
    culture = this.findClosestCulture( cultureSelector );
    if ( value instanceof Date ) {
        value = formatDate( value, format, culture );
    }
    else if ( typeof value === "number" ) {
        value = formatNumber( value, format, culture );
    }
    return value;
};
```

In my page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td[globalize="true"]').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var cellText = $this.text();
        if (cellText != null) {
            var n = new Number(cellText);
            var v = Globalize.formatNumber(n, _gloNum[0]);
            $this.text(v);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The problem is that the typeof my cell contents is 'object' and not
>   'number'

When you do:

```
new Number
```

You are creating ***new*** instance of *Number* object, that's why it gives you object and not number.

> Is there a way I can coerce the data to be typeof number?

```
var n = +(cellText);
```

Or

```
var n = Number(cellText);
```

Comment: This is the best answer. It correctly shows how to cast to a number primitive properly. It's best never to use `new Number`.

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript `new Number` returns a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) object. Have a look at [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) or [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Change:

```
var n = new Number(cellText);
```

To

```
var n = Number(cellText);
```

Or

```
var n = parseFloat(cellText);
```

Or

```
var n = parseInt(cellText, 10);
```

Depending on what you need.

Answer (score 2):

`new Number(cellText)` returns a `Number` object, not a `number` primitive.

Use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` instead.

```
var cellText = '12.34',
a = new Number(cellText), // 12.34, but a Number object
b = parseInt(cellText, 10), // 12
c = parseFloat(cellText); // 12.34

typeof a; // 'object'
a instanceof Number; // true

typeof b; // 'number'
typeof c; // 'number'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `typeof` is buggy in JavaScript. I suggest you use the following function instead:

```
function typeOf(value) {
    if (value === null) return "null";
    else if (typeof value === "undefined") return "undefined";
    else return Object.prototype.toString.call(value).slice(8, -1);
}
```